# What does this typedef declaration mean?

Tags: c, typedef, kernighan-and-ritchie

I know about `typedef` in C, but I got confused when I saw a declaration in the K&R book.  The declaration is

```
typedef int (*PFI) (char *,char *)
```

What does it mean?  What is `PFI` and how can we use it in our program?

Comment: Read up on function pointers.

Comment: `PFI` is a pointer to a function that takes two `char *` arguments and returns an `int`.

Comment: I don't think you read about function pointers in those 15 minutes.

Comment: The two authors discuss function pointers quite thoroughly. In chapter 6.7 where they introduce `typedef` and give this example they say *in the same sentence* that this declaration 'creates the type PFI, for "pointer to function (of two char * arguments) returning int," [which answers your first question] which can be used in contexts like `PFI strcmp, numcmp;`in the sort program of chapter 5' -- which is where they introduced and discussed function pointers, answering your second question. Did you miss all that?

Answer (score 4):

Breaking it down, `PFI` is a pointer:

```
*PFI
```

To a function:

```
(*PFI)()
```

Which takes two arguments of type `char *`:

```
(*PFI)(char *, char *)
```

And returns an `int`:

```
int (*PFI)(char *, char *)
```

And declared as an alias of that type:

```
typedef int (*PFI)(char *, char *);
```

You could use it if you had a function that matches this pointer type, i.e:

```
int foo(char *x, char *y)
{
    ...
}
```

Then you can assign a pointer to the function to a variable of type `PFI`:

```
PFI f = &foo;
```

Answer (score 2):

were you reading about pointer to functions?

If yes, then PFI is just a placeholder. It can be whatever name you give, it is just a function name. I guess it could mean "Preferred Function Interface" but that is just a guess.

so let's say you write a very crude code something like

```
typedef bool (*write_X_Bytes) (uint32 count, char *buffer);
```

then you can use it as a type in C since you used typedef in front of it like

```
write_X_Bytes print_line, print_word;
```

basically you give a prototype to user or whoever wants to use this code about parameters and return. You can checkout Linux kernel driver code for GPIO for real life usecase.

Answer (score 2):

Basic rules of pointer declarations:

```
T *p;        // p is a pointer to T
T *ap[N];    // ap is an N-element array of pointers to T
T *fp();     // fp is a function returning a pointer to T

T (*pa)[N];  // pa is a pointer to an array of T
T (*pf)();   // pf is a pointer to a function returning T
```

In both expressions and declarators, the subscript `[]` and function call `()` operators have higher precedence than the unary dereference `*` operator, so an expression or declarator like `*f()` is parsed as `*(f())` - you are dereferencing the result of `f`.  If you want to dereference `f` *before* calling it, you have to explicitly group the `*` operator with it - `(*f)()`.

The way to read a hairy declaration is to start with the leftmost identifier and work your way out according to the rules above, applying them recursively to any function parameters.

If you have a function that uses abstract declarators in the parameter list like this one, just remember:

```
T *       -> T *λ
T *[N]    -> T *λ[N] 
T (*)[N]  -> T (*λ)[N]
T *()     -> T *λ()
T (*)()   -> T (*λ)()
```

where `λ` represents where the identifier would normally go.

So, the way to read this declaration is as

```
              PFI                     -- PFI
typedef       PFI                     -- is a typedef name for 
typedef      *PFI                     -- pointer to
typedef     (*PFI) (             )    --   a function taking
typedef     (*PFI) (             )    --     unnamed parameter
typedef     (*PFI) (     *       )    --       is a pointer to
typedef     (*PFI) (char *       )    --         char
typedef     (*PFI) (char *,      )    --     unnamed parameter
typedef     (*PFI) (char *,     *)    --       is a pointer to
typedef     (*PFI) (char *,char *)    --         char
typedef int (*PFI) (char *,char *);   --   returning int
```

In less formal terms, PFI is an alias for the type "pointer to a function taking two `char *` parameters and returning `int`".

So how would we use this?

A common use is declaring callbacks in function parameter lists:

```
void foo( char *foo, char *bar, PFI callback )
{
  int x = callback( foo, bar );
  ...
}
```

That's a little easier to read than

```
void foo( char *foo, char *bar, int (*callback)(char *, char *) )
{
  int x = callback( foo, bar );
  ...
}
```

It's also useful for declaring arrays or `struct` members:

```
int func1( char *x, char *y ) { ... }
int func2( char *a, char *b ) { ... }
...

struct s {
  char *x;
  char *y;
  PFI f;
} blah = {"foo", "bar", func1};

PFI callbacks[] = { func1, func2, ... };
```

Again, that's a bit cleaner than writing

```
struct s {
  char *x;
  char *y;
  int (*f)(char *, char *);
};
```

or

```
int (*callbacks[])(char *, char *) = { func1, func2, ... };
```

But...

"Being a bit cleaner" is not, by itself, sufficient reason to hide the type behind a `typedef`.  You use a `typedef` to abstract away details about a type that the user of the type *doesn't need to know about* in order to use it.

For example, consider the `FILE` type in `stdio.h`.  There is an entire API supporting the `FILE` type, such that you never need to know what it looks like under the hood.

In our case, however, we *have to know* that a `PFI` is a pointer to a function expecting two `char *` arguments and returning an `int` in order to use it.  Using the typedef name saves a few keystrokes, but it also creates a "leaky" abstraction, since details about the type have to "leak" out to the programmer.  In this case, it's honestly better to forego the `typedef` altogether and use the "naked" declaration.

Answer (score 1):

https://cdecl.org/ says "declare PFI as pointer to function (pointer to char, pointer to char) returning int".  That website didn't like the initial typedef but that makes it a type so you can you write:

`PFI fp = f;`

where `f` would have the prototype:

`int f(char *, char *);`

Answer (score 1):

PFI just means "Pointer to a function returning int".  It's a fast way to create a type that can be used quickly in code, because otherwise the syntax is complicated.

As one example, it's very useful for callback interfaces. You may want to define something like PFContext_t as a pointer to a function taking certain arguments and returning a context pointer.  Then you can use the typedef in your data (if, for instance, you want to keep the pointer in a structure), and you can use the typedef in the arguments to a function called by the client, setting the callback.