# Is it really legal for K&R to write "PFI strcmp, numcmp;" where PFI is typedef'd as "int (*)(char *, char *)"?

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef, kernighan-and-ritchie

In *The C Programming Language* (Kernighan and Ritchie, 2nd ed) on p147, the authors show a `typedef` declaration

```
typedef int (*PFI)(char *, char *);
```

(`PFI` stands for "pointer to function returning an `int`"), which they claim

> can be used in contexts like
>
> ```
> PFI strcmp, numcmp;
> ```
>
> in the sort program of Chapter 5.

There, `strcmp` is either K&R's version from p106¹ or the version from `<string.h>` in the standard library², and `numcmp` (p121) is a function which converts its arguments to `double`s before comparing them numerically:

```
int strcmp(char *s1, char *s2);
int numcmp(char *s1, char *s2);
```

¹ It really should be named `strcmp_kr` to avoid conflicts with the standard library, but this point is not relevant for this question.
² It technically takes `const char *` arguments, but this difference is not relevant for this question.

The sort program they are referring to is the one in section 5.11 (p118-121). (While [it is independently problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76241319/2057969) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65425350/15168)), the reasons have no bearing on this question.)

I understand all that K&R are doing, but I can't make sense of their statement about "contexts like `PFI strcmp, numcmp;`". The function signatures of the function designators `strcmp` and `numcmp` are as stated just above. Adding a declaration like `PFI strcmp;` or `PFI numcmp;` would lead to a compiler error, as `strcmp` and `numcmp` are function designators (with function types); they don't have a function pointer type such as `PFI`, even though they are automatically converted to function pointers in most contexts (C17 standard draft, 6.3.2.1 ¶4) – which is a subtlety.

That is, I can't come up with a decent example where one can actually write something like `PFI strcmp, numcmp;`. Let's try such a thing, but with a simplified toy function `lencmp` which compares strings simply by comparing their lengths:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int (*PFI)(char *, char *);
int lencmp(char *, char *);

int main(void) {
    PFI cmp = &lencmp;

    printf("%d\n", (*cmp)("de", "abc"));  /* -1 */
    printf("%d\n", (*cmp)("def", "abc"));  /* 0 */
    printf("%d\n", (*cmp)("def", "ab"));  /* 1 */

    return 0;
}

int lencmp(char *s, char *t) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(s), len2 = strlen(t);
    return (len1 > len2) - (len1 < len2);
}
```

(That one can equivalently write bare `PFI cmp = lencmp;` in the assignment and bare `cmp(...)` in the function calls is not what this question is about.)

Well, the above code works and illustrates how one can legally use `PFI`. But we wouldn't be able to declare `lencmp` like this

```
PFI lencmp;
```

because this would lead to an error due to the initial declaration mismatching the later definition of `lencmp`.

**What do K&R mean by "contexts like `PFI strcmp, numcmp;`"?** Is this legal? Isn't this simply a **semantic error in K&R**? Surely one could define variables of the function pointer type `PFI` (that is: `int (*)(char *, char *)`) and assign `strcmp` and `numcmp` to them

```
PFI fp1 = &strcmp;
PFI fp2 = &numcmp;
```

but we wouldn't be able to name those variables `strcmp` and `numcmp`. (However, as commenter KamilCuk pointed out, we could rename `cmp` within the function `main` to one of these names.)

Incidentally, what does work is a `typedef` to a direct function type:

```
typedef int FI(char *, char *);
FI lencmp;
```

- For an official example of this style, see the C17 standard draft (6.7.8 ¶7), which does this for `signal` from `<signal.h>`.
- Given that this style [was already legal in C89/C90](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76676848/2057969), it's surprising that K&R don't use it in their book.

Note that I am *not* asking about the following:

- the [meaning of the given `typedef` itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66557917/2057969), which it clear to me
- the [interchangeability of functions (`f`/`*fp`) and function pointers (`&f`/`fp`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76217910/2057969) in most contexts

Comment: In standard C it's not allowed. In old pre-standard "traditional" K&R C it's allowed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks; by "it" you mean the line `PFI strcmp, numcmp;`? If so, it looks like I found an as-of-yet undiscovered erratum in K&R (ie they forgot to update that line for their 2nd edition).

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion. Declaring variables with the same name as functions is not allowed in standard C. K&R C is very slack when it comes to things like type and type-checking, and perhaps e.g. `PFI strcmp;` is considered a forward declaration (which aren't always needed in K&R C).

Comment: Btw, I just checked; the corresponding page in the 1st ed of K&R is p141.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see, so *perhaps* what K&R meant was: `PFI strcmp, numcmp;` would be a valid declaration for identically-named function pointer variables in pre-standard C.

Comment: I don't have the original Ritchie's compiler to check the claim but it doesn't make a lot of sense to me. `PFI numcmp` declares a pointer to function, not a function. One can declare (but not define) functions this way: `typedef int FI(char*, char*); FI numcmp;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Or (your idea – I'm just rewording things for other people for clarification) a potential valid forward declaration, despite the slight mismatch in types (raw function type vs function pointer type).

Comment: Inside a function, I believe `PFI strcmp, numcmp;` declares two uninitialized function pointers and hides any external function names spelt the same way.  Outside a function, they are still function pointers, and they should conflict with any functions with the same name in the object files linked into the program (and the name `strcmp` could cause complications for a program trying to use the standard library `strcmp()` function — and an awful lot of programs fall into that category).  I think that the claim on p147 of K&R2 is dubious.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler A quick test of mine with GCC (C89/C90) indeed has such a function-internal declaration create function pointers that shadow function names. (I won't bother to check the standard for this for now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the first edition of *The C Programming Language* (1978), and the answer is:

Kernighan and Ritchie **updated the following text from the 1st edition** (1e: p141)

> For example,
>
> ```
> typedef int (*PFI)();
> ```
>
> creates the type `PFI`, for "pointer to function returning `int`," which can be used in contexts like
>
> ```
> PFI strcmp, numcmp, swap;
> ```
>
> in the sort program of Chapter 5.

**in an incomplete/erroneous way** for the 2nd edition, which reads (2e: p147):

> For example,
>
> ```
> typedef int (*PFI)(char *, char *);
> ```
>
> creates the type `PFI`, for "pointer to function (of two `char *` arguments) returning `int`," which can be used in contexts like
>
> ```
> PFI strcmp, numcmp;
> ```
>
> in the sort program of Chapter 5.

The text in the first edition refers to the following code (1e: sec5.12 (Pointers to Functions), p115; some comments removed):

> ```
> #define LINES 100
>
> main(argc, argv)    /* sort input lines */
> int argc;
> char *argv[];
> {
>      char *lineptr[LINES];
>      int nlines;
>      int strcmp(), numcmp(); /* comparison functions */
>      int swap();   /* exchange function */
>      numeric = 0;
>      
>      <body of function>
> }
> ```
>
> `strcmp`, `numcmp` and `swap` are addresses of functions; since they are known to be functions, the `&` operator is not necessary, in the same way that it is not needed before an array name.

(Don't get confused by the part of the last sentence after the semicolon about the missing ampersand `&`: this applies to the code in the body of `main` (not shown here) and equally applies in the 2nd ed; it is not relevant for the issue discussed in this post.)

The corresponding text in the 2nd edition (2e: sec5.11 (Pointers to Functions), p119) has `strcmp` and `numcmp` declared (not within `main` but) at file scope, and `swap` appears (not in that code excerpt but) only later when it is called from their `qsort` (p120) and when it is defined (p121).

That is, the line `PFI strcmp, numcmp, swap;` from their 1st ed is intended to replace the `main`-internal declarations

```
int strcmp(), numcmp();
int swap();
```

and **the corresponding version `PFI strcmp, numcmp;` from their 2nd ed doesn't make sense; it should have been taken out entirely**.

The implication from the 1st ed text is that declaring the *functions* `strcmp`/`numcmp`/`swap` with a function *pointer* type was acceptable in K&R C. Whether this was truly so or there is a mistake on p141 (1e) is something that I can't judge.

Comment: But `int strcmp(), numcmp(); int swap();` in the 1st Edition is quite different from what `PFI strcmp, numcmp, swap;` declares.  The first declares 3 functions; the second declares 3 pointers to functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's pretty clear from the 1st ed text that this is the only thing they could have meant, and the direct implication is that this mismatch was okay in K&R C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler On second thought ... this discrepancy does deserve pointing out; see my latest edit.

Answer (score 3):

The succinct answer to the headline question ("Is it really legal for K&R to write `PFI strcmp, numcmp;` where PFI is typedef'd as `int (*)(char *, char *)`?") is "Yes".

However, what that does depends on where the definition appears, and it probably wasn't what was intended, so the answer is more like a "Yes, but…".

Inside a function, `PFI strcmp, numcmp;` declares two uninitialized function pointers and hides any external function names spelt the same way.  Once initialized to non-null pointers to appropriate functions, they can be used the same as any other function pointer.  Note, however, that there isn't a simple way to make them point to the functions `strcmp()` or `numcmp()` — those names have been hidden.  (You could do it by passing the addresses of the pointer variables to a function that assigns the right pointers, but that's rather circuitous.)

Outside a function, they are still function pointers, and they should conflict with any functions with the same name in the object files linked into the program. The name `strcmp` could cause complications for a program trying to use the standard library `strcmp()` function — and an awful lot of programs fall into that category.

You can't declare functions using a typedef for the type of the function.  The definition:

```
PFI strcmp, numcmp;
```

is not equivalent to:

```
extern int strcmp(char *s1, char *s2);
extern int numcmp(char *s1, char *s2);
```

(with or without the optional `extern` storage class).

Consequently, I think that the claim on p147 of K&R is dubious — either lacking sufficient context to show what they were thinking or actually erroneous.

<sup>I'm ignoring the issue that the standard C type for `strcmp()` does not match the type used by K&R in the book.  It is largely tangential to the question.</sup>

- [K&R] Brian W Kernighan and Dennis M Ritchie
  [The C Programming Language, 2nd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) 1988.